# Simple $.getJSON("adress"),function(res){ does not wok

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a simple function:

```
setInterval(function () {
    $.getJSON("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/?ids=1234567_1234567&fields=reactions.type(LIKE).limit(0).summary(total_count).as(reactions_like)%2Creactions.type(LOVE).limit(0).summary(total_count).as(reactions_love)&access_token=thatsmytoken"),
        function (res) {

            console.log(res);

        };
}, 5000);
```

So it should call GET and show the result in console but its not...
I can see the result of GET in network info in Chrome (every 5 seconds it works fine) but its not going inside the function(res)

Why is that?

Comment: Missing closing `)` at `$.getJSON()`. Have you tried passing URL to `encodeURIComponent()` or `escape()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parentheses are incorrect.  It should be:

```
setInterval(function () {
    $.getJSON("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/?ids=1234567_1234567&fields=reactions.type(LIKE).limit(0).summary(total_count).as(reactions_like)%2Creactions.type(LOVE).limit(0).summary(total_count).as(reactions_love)&access_token=thatsmytoken",
        function (res) {

            console.log(res);

        });
}, 5000);
```

Now, function(res){...} will be the callback of the getJSON function if it succeeds.  Click [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) for more information about the callbacks.

Comment: I'm dumb... THANK YOU! :)